# Print out only finished memberList

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, arraylist

so the Code looks like this right now.

**The Problem is that I get more than one Logprints. But I need only the full and finished meberList.**

```
for (String memberByNumber : memberListByNumber) {
                    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("userUidsByNumber/").child(memberByNumber).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                String userUid = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                                memberList.add(userUid);

                                Log.d("LOL", "ContactsAdapter: " + memberList);
                            } else {
                                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.user_does_not_exist, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Snackbar.make(view, R.string.error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

I hope you understand my Problem and can help me. 
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Well, when you set it to log on every entry you will get more than one output

Comment: @Zoe Yeah, but how to get only the finished memberList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `onDataChange` gets called for every member for `memberListByNumber`, then you can try

```
final int total = memberListByNumber.size();
for (String memberByNumber : memberListByNumber) {
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference
            .child("userUidsByNumber/")
            .child(memberByNumber)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        int n = total;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String userUid = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                memberList.add(userUid);
                if (--n <= 0) Log.d("LOL", "ContactsAdapter: " + memberList);
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.user_does_not_exist, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Snackbar.make(view, R.string.error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment it but due to my reputation here I couldn't 
So, here is my answer your logging every entry into one file so that it just makes printing the necessary entries much harder So go on different path and give one more if-else statement in existing one and use try-exception to divide the finished and canceled into some cache memory and then void the finished file

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, there's never a thing as complete list.

Value events keep happening whenever any data changes under any of the child nodes. Also value events happen last ie after all child events are finished ensuring all children nodes at that point are present. Next event will give you the complete list at that particular point.

On each data change call, you can clear the list, add all the new values and print that. This is how firebase works.

If you want the entire list only once and don't want any new changes, you can add the value event listeners using addListenerForSingleValueEvent method. Now the list will be read once and no more. However if you have persistence enabled, the data will be read once from the phone cache and not from the db

Maybe what you are looking for is a ChildEventListener which will give you more granular control. This will have child added, deleted and changed events which will give you the list data one child at a time.

I don't know what your actual purpose is so this is the best i can try to explain. Hope this helps